# IOAccelSurface2 error floods console macOS 10.12 Sierra

Tags: mac, macos, console

I have a MB Pro that is locking up afer about 30 minutes.
When I open console I find this message but cant figure out what is causing the problem.

> fault 12:14:37.463057 -0700 kernel IOReturn
>   IOAccelSurface2::surface_unlock_options(enum eLockType, uint32_t):
>   surface is not locked.

Answer (score 1):

We had a user at our company that was having some performance issues on their Mac. So I connected remotely via Timbuktu and took a look at their console. I noticed a constant flood of similar errors:

fault   11:48:36.982151 -0500   kernel  IOReturn IOAccelSurface2::surface_unlock_options(enum eLockType, uint32_t): surface is not locked.

So I removed TeamViewer but the errors persisted. After spending about an hour trying to resolve the problem I discovered that the console flood was a "[red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring)". The flood was being triggered by Timbuktu and my remote connection to the computer. As soon as I disconnected the user told me that the console flood stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the exact same error popping up if a TeamViewer Session is established. An internet search brings up this [discussion](https://origin-discussions-us.apple.com/thread/7689947?start=0&tstart=0).

Propably, its an incompatibility bug for TeamViewer 11 with Sierra.

```
Problem 10:31:54.180203 +0100   kernel  IOReturn IOAccelSurface2::surface_unlock_options(enum eLockType, uint32_t): surface is not locked.
Problem 10:31:54.259101 +0100   kernel  IOReturn IOAccelSurface2::surface_unlock_options(enum eLockType, uint32_t): surface is not locked.
Problem 10:31:54.334998 +0100   kernel  IOReturn IOAccelSurface2::surface_unlock_options(enum eLockType, uint32_t): surface is not locked.
Problem 10:31:54.411823 +0100   kernel  IOReturn IOAccelSurface2::surface_unlock_options(enum eLockType, uint32_t): surface is not locked.
Problem 10:31:54.484102 +0100   kernel  IOReturn IOAccelSurface2::surface_unlock_options(enum eLockType, uint32_t): surface is not locked.
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall TeamViewer with AppCleaner and reboot. That solved it for me.